# Unable to find FirebaseCppApp

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

We integrated Firebase into one of our projects. The project runs well and works perfectly in the editor, but when ran on an Android device I get the following output on logcat:

```
01-04 11:18:04.789 12651-12651/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
01-04 11:18:20.897 12823-13015/? W/Ads: Invoke Firebase method getInstance error.
    The Google Mobile Ads SDK will not integrate with Firebase. Admob/Firebase integration requires the latest Firebase SDK jar, but Firebase SDK is either missing or out of date
01-04 11:18:21.113 12823-12878/? E/Unity: Unable to find FirebaseCppApp-5.4.3
01-04 11:18:21.233 12823-12878/? E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: FirebaseCppApp-5.4.3
        at (wrapper managed-to-native) Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper:SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate,Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE/SWIGExceptionHelper/ExceptionDelegate)
      at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initialize
```

It seems some DLL cannot be found. I've ran the **Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver > Force Resolve** in the Unity Editor, and resolving outputs success. We've also tried re-importing the Firebase package, alas, to no avail.

Comment: A quick update. I tried creating a new project from scratch and adding ONLY a blank screen and one script with the firebase init code and one single login event for testing. I get the same error, however. Could this be a developing environment problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who is stuck with this same issue:

I was missing the NDK installation. NDK is responsible for loading DLLs and C/C++ native code into Android Applications. Unity doesn't give you a clear enough message if you're missing this development kit, it just ignores this fact and builds the app without the DLLs apparently.

After installing the NDK, all I had to do was force resolve the Android Dependencies and the error was resolved.